# NodeJS - Go to a site without actually visiting it?

Tags: node.js

Okay so what I am trying to achieve here is that I have made an PHP script with a bunch of $_GET's.

So I would like to go to a website without actually visiting it with NodeJS. Basically to trigger this script with parameters.

I hope that explains what I am trying to do. I really have no idea how to make it trigger a site or whatever you can call it - hence why not posting anything that I have tried before posting this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to make http requests to the site with node.js ? Or what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an HTTP request from node, you may use the standard [http package](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). You'll find examples in the standard documentation.

To make them in a simpler way, you may also use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. Using it, a http request is as simple as that :

```
var request = require('request');
request("https://yourwebsite.com/page.php?a=b", function(error, res, body){
    if (error) console.log("error:", error);
    else console.log('body of the response :', body);
})
```